# What are the criteria for re-combining?

Tags: agar.io

After you launch half your mass, it seems that you can't immediately re-combine your separate masses into one bigger cell.

Is this based on some amount of time, or some other criteria? Exactly what do I have to do before I can re-combine back into one big mass?

Comment: I've noticed that larger cells seem to take longer to recombine. I may try different movement patterns with cells of the same size to see if it affects how long recombining takes.

Comment: Yes, well, clearly you should move in such a manner that the larger cell is ahead of the smaller cell so the smaller cell will overtake the larger cell and  merge.

Answer (score 7):

The time to recombine is based on the size of the offshoots. When the cell is split, every individual cell has a timer storing how long until they are able to recombine. There may be a component that if you have cells much smaller than your largest cell the timers for the small cells are reduced.

**Edit:** 
So having looked through the source code at the link @BitCoder provided, I had it partially correct. The server has a base recombine time, currently 30 seconds. When a new cell is created (either via the player splitting, or running into a virus), the server sets the recombine time to be:

> 30 sec + (.02 * mass))

In summary: the recombine time of each cell is thirty seconds plus one additional second for every 50 mass the cell has when it is created.

Comment: How long is the timer? What's the formula?

Comment: I don't think the source code is public, so this information is just from a number of hours of playing the game. Only hard number I know about the game is that a mass of 130 is the size that activates the virus balls.

Comment: An interesting idea might be to go into settings (the gear icon before you start the game, or in the 'escape' dialog during the game (which will likely get you killed)) and turn on the 'show mass' checkbox, and then split and time it.  With a graph of the data we could probably figure out the algorithm.  One question might be whether splitting into four 100-mass balls has the same recombine time as splitting into two 100-mass balls.

Comment: @Dead I believe that the server source code can be found here: https://github.com/forairan/Ogar. And size 125 activates green viruses. 200 for red viruses.